# Laravel Eloquent - sorting parent based on child relationship attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a `Product` which has multiple `Variants`.

I want to select all Products and sort them based on the price of first underlying variant child.

**Product A**

- Variant A1 (price: $3)
- Variant A2 (price: $3)

**Product B**

- Variant B1 (price: $2)
- Variant B2 (price: $2)

**Product C**

- Variant C1 (price: $4)
- Variant C2 (price: $4)

In this case if i want to order on price `asc` i expect to get the following result ordering:

- Product B
- Product A
- Product C

My current (not working) query:

```
Product::with(['variants' => function ($q) {
   $q->orderBy('price', 'desc');
}])->orderBy('variants.price', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: Does the variants prices are always the same for particular product?

Comment: It's a bit of a weird scenario i realise that but yeah they can be different, however in this scenario it is irrelevant - that's why it would be great to be able to filter on the first found.

Comment: How about max price instead of first found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by using the following query:

```
Product::join('variants', function ($join) {
   $join->on('variants.product_id', '=', 'products.id');
})
   ->select('products.*', DB::raw("MAX(variants.price) as max_variant_price"))
   ->groupBy('variants.product_id')
   ->orderBy('max_variant_price')
   ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not order by when using `with()`:
Because `with()` will make two separate queries like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users;
SELECT * FROM roles WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4, whatever...);
```

The solution for your problem is use `join()` so you make only one query:

```php
$order = 'desc';
$products = Product::join('variants', 'variants.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->orderBy('products. price', $order)
    ->select('products.*')
    ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Order them after the fetch.

```php
$products = Product::with('variants')
    ->get()
    ->sortBy(function($product) {
        // if you want to order by first found
        return $product->variants->first()->price;

        // if you want to order by max price
        return $product->variants->max->price;

        // or min price
        return $product->variants->min->price;

        // or average price
        return $product->variants->average->price;
    });
```

Comment: i have pagination so that's not ideal, is there no way to order before the `get()` ?

Comment: If someone is pulling a large dataset this is not ideal. Ideally it comes back ordered otherwise doing it after the fact means all the models need to be hydrated causing performance issues.

Comment: agreed. not suitable for large dataset and pagination